# DATAGRIDVIEW Vb.Net 2010

Tags: datagridview

Can anybody tell me that how can we impose formula on datagridview in vb.net .Actually I want to perform a multiplication operation of two column's value and store the result into the third column automatically when I give the value into the first two columns. 
Suppose first column name is A, and second column name is B and third column name is C. 
So whenever I give the value on A and B then column C must show the multiplication result of A and B automatically. 
anybody can please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  dt.Columns.Add("A", GetType(Double))
  dt.Columns.Add("B", GetType(Double))
  dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(Double))
  dt.Columns("C").Expression = "A * B"
  DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: thnx dear for ur response